# gearman and multiple curl requests

Tags: php, curl, gearman

How can I run multiple curl requests in parallel with gearman i'm a bit confused with the documentation:

My questions are: 
**1. Where do I run the RunCurl(); function in client or worker?** 
**2. Do I need to pass a $job reference to the RunCurl(); function?**  
**3. Where is `addFunction('lookup_user')` defined?**

```
public function RunCurl()
{
//do curl request 
//get list of IP's from database
//run Curl request


}
```

### Client

```
public function parallel_client()

{
$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();

// initialize the results of our 3 "query results" here
$userInfo ='single';
$friends ='none';
$posts = 'jones';

// This sets up what gearman will callback to as tasks are returned to us.
// The $context helps us know which function is being returned so we can 
// handle it correctly.
$client->setCompleteCallback(function(GearmanTask $task, $context) use (&$userInfo, &$friends, &$posts) {
    switch($context) {
        case 'lookup_user':
            $userInfo = $task->data();      
            break;
        case 'baconate':
            $friends = $task->data();
            break;
        case 'get_latest_posts_by':
            $posts = $task->data();
            break;
    }
});

// Here we queue up multiple tasks to be execute in *as much* parallelism as gearmand can give us
$client->addTask('lookup_user', 'joe@joe.com', 'lookup_user');
$client->addTask('baconate', 'joe@joe.com', 'baconate');
$client->addTask('get_latest_posts_by', 'joe@joe.com', 'get_latest_posts_by');

echo "Fetching...\n";
$start = microtime(true);
$client->runTasks();
$totaltime = number_format(microtime(true) - $start, 2);

echo "Got user info in: $totaltime seconds:\n";
var_dump($userInfo, $friends, $posts);


}
```

### Worker

```
public function parallel_worker()
{
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();

$worker->addFunction('lookup_user', function(GearmanJob $job){
    // normally you'd so some very safe type checking and query binding to a database here.
    // ...and we're gonna fake that.
    //sleep(3);
    //$this->RunCurl();
    return 'The user requested ('. $job->workload() .') is 7 feet tall and awesome!';
});

$worker->addFunction('baconate', function(GearmanJob $job){
   // sleep(3);
    return 'The user ('. $job->workload() .') is 1 degree away from Kevin Bacon';
});

$worker->addFunction('get_latest_posts_by', function(GearmanJob $job){
   // sleep(3);
    return 'The user ('. $job->workload() .') has no posts, sorry!';
});

while ($worker->work());


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Where do I run the RunCurl(); function in client or worker?

I believe you want this in your worker.  I say 'believe' because at the end of the day it's up to you where you put it, but if you want the `RunCurl()` call to be processed off of your webserver (which *is* the client), then you need to put it in the worker.

> 1. Do I need to pass a $job reference to the RunCurl(); function?

Most likely.  You really only need the job reference passed in if you are either passing data to the worker or passing data back from the worker (or calling any other function on the job, such as `sendException`).  You probably will need to at the very least provide some sort of input to your worker, though it is not required.

> 1. Where is addFunction('lookup_user') defined?

The `addFunction` method is defined on the `GearmanWorker` object inside of the PECL Gearman extension. See documentation for that class [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.gearmanworker.php),  or see the C source for this function [here](https://github.com/hjr3/pecl-gearman/blob/master/php_gearman.c#L3625).

And last but not least, your overall question: How can I run multiple curl requests in parallel with gearman?

The idea behind gearman is to offload processing to something else that is designed to handle processing specific jobs.  There are basically three types of calls when dealing with gearman: "Fire and Forget" where you shuttle the job off to the worker and then forget about it (where I think gearman excels the most), "Blocking" service calls where the client will actually sit and wait for the worker to return some data, and "Send Me Status Updates" where you send the job off and then send nothing but status updates back from the worker to the client.

You can handle performing multiple service calls in parallel by starting a whole bunch of worker processes and then submitting a bunch of jobs to those workers.  gearmand itself is nothing more than a queuing service that keeps track of what workers are registered/available and assigns jobs as they come in to available workers.  Once a worker has a job, it is no longer available until that job is complete.  By running multiple worker processes though you can theoretically handle some finite number of tasks in parallel (where the number of tasks you can handle in parallel is equal to the number of worker processes you started).

Comment: so in order for me to run 5 curl requests in parallel I need to setup 5 workers? so from command line it would be something like `$app index.php/controller_name parallel_worker` 5 times, then run `parallel_client`?

Comment: correct. in terminal I would probably have an application wrapped around my workers, so it would be more like `$ php my_worker_script.php` in 5 different terminal windows.  You can still handle 5 requests with 2 workers, but its only going to process them 2 at any given time.